# Getting Beautiful soup to read in tables

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-table

My first post in stack overflow, and I am also fairly new to the world of Beautiful Soup, so pls be kind.

I am trying to learn web scraping, and in particular, I want to be able to extract data from a government website. See code extract below:

```
url = 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/rainfall-monthly-total?view_id=be92ce92-d02e-4920-9479-ff6da87b45e8&resource_id=778814b8-1b96-404b-9ac9-68d6c00e637b'

# Persists parameters across requests
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

# Look for iframe, and src as attribute
iframe_src = soup.select_one("iframe").attrs["src"]
r = s.get(f"{iframe_src}")
print("Data Table is extracted from: ", iframe_src)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
#print(soup.prettify())

rows = soup.findAll("tr", {'class': ['odd', 'even']})
dat = []

for row in rows:
    dat.append( map( str, row.findAll('td')))
```

As you can see, I was just trying to directly extract the table data, with the eventual goal of converting it to csv. However, for some reason, I cant seem to see any table data when I execute the code

Upon further reading, I learnt BeautifulSoup does not work with Javascript. I suspect that is the cause, and my preliminary investigation of teh data set seems to indicate this to be the case, but I am not sure. Thus,

1) Is the reason for the lack of output precisely that i.e. Javascript?
2) I read Selenium can be used - how do I incoporate it here?
3) I have multiple pages; how do I get all the data into 1 csv table?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If learning to web scrape with Beautiful Soup, I think you have the right idea to go after a table (although once you learn Beautiful Soup to extract `<table>` tags, you should really use pandas as it'll make it a lot easier. But tables are a good way to understand how to work through tags in html.
2. I would advise to start with a different site. You are correct that this is js rendered, so you would need to have the html rendered first (by something like Selenium) to then go and parse the html. Since you are just starting off, don't over complicate by having to learn bs4 and Selenium. [Here's a good site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_(United_Nations)) to practice scraping a table. Still a a little tricky, but a static table to play on.
3. This table can be pulled from a separate request URL that returns a JSON response. You can take that JSON and easily turn that into a table with pandas (see code below). Any API, or such, that you can use is the preferred method. The data comes in a nice JSON structure (sometimes not as nice, but at least consistent), and you don't necessarily have to iterate through "pages":

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/5942f8bd-4240-4f68-acd2-a5a276958237/resource/778814b8-1b96-404b-9ac9-68d6c00e637b/data'
payload = {'limit':'2000'}

# Persists parameters across requests
s = requests.Session()
jsonData = s.get(url, params=payload).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['records'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
     _id    month total_rainfall
0    459  2020-03          108.8
1    458  2020-02             65
2    457  2020-01           88.4
3    456  2019-12          421.5
4    455  2019-11          137.4
5    454  2019-10          176.8
6    453  2019-09           22.8
7    452  2019-08           11.8
8    451  2019-07           12.2
9    450  2019-06          173.8
10   449  2019-05             69
11   448  2019-04          174.8
12   447  2019-03           72.2
13   446  2019-02           31.6
14   445  2019-01           63.6
15   444  2018-12          172.6
16   443  2018-11          169.6
17   442  2018-10          234.4
18   441  2018-09          144.4
19   440  2018-08          121.6
20   439  2018-07          143.2
21   438  2018-06          182.6
22   437  2018-05          132.2
23   436  2018-04           61.2
24   435  2018-03           44.6
25   434  2018-02           14.8
26   433  2018-01            287
27   432  2017-12          371.2
28   431  2017-11          268.6
29   430  2017-10          120.8
..   ...      ...            ...
429   30  1984-06            255
430   29  1984-05          186.5
431   28  1984-04          153.1
432   27  1984-03          361.3
433   26  1984-02          470.4
434   25  1984-01          251.2
435   24  1983-12          370.6
436   23  1983-11          228.8
437   22  1983-10          212.7
438   21  1983-09          170.8
439   20  1983-08          262.2
440   19  1983-07            190
441   18  1983-06             94
442   17  1983-05          160.8
443   16  1983-04           33.6
444   15  1983-03           18.6
445   14  1983-02            5.6
446   13  1983-01            246
447   12  1982-12          494.1
448   11  1982-11            134
449   10  1982-10           39.3
450    9  1982-09           54.1
451    8  1982-08          169.5
452    7  1982-07           76.3
453    6  1982-06           59.5
454    5  1982-05          102.2
455    4  1982-04            157
456    3  1982-03          160.8
457    2  1982-02           27.8
458    1  1982-01          107.1

[459 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will take a look at the links as you suggested